# MySQL getting total number of enquiries for each branch

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables and they are the following

**User Table**

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| user_id | user_name | branch |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 1       | John      | 1      |
| 2       | Jim       | 2      |
| 3       | Jern      | 3      |
| 4       | Jack      | 1      |
| 5       | Jery      | 2      |
| 6       | Tom       | 3      |
| 7       | Sona      | 1      |
| 8       | Tina      | 3      |   
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

**Branch Table**

```
+-----------+----------------+
| branch_id | branch_name    |
+-----------+----------------+
| 1         | IT             |
| 2         | SALES          |
| 3         | Administration |
+-----------+----------------+
```

**Enquiry Table**

```
+------------+---------------+---------+
| enquiry_id | enquiry_name  | user_id |
+------------+---------------+---------+
| 1          | enqury_test1  | 1       |
| 2          | enqury_test2  | 2       |
| 3          | enqury_test3  | 1       |
| 4          | enqury_test4  | 3       |
| 5          | enqury_test5  | 2       |
| 6          | enqury_test6  | 5       |
| 7          | enqury_test7  | 1       |
| 8          | enqury_test8  | 2       |
| 9          | enqury_test9  | 4       |
| 10         | enqury_test10 | 6       |
| 11         | enqury_test11 | 2       |
| 12         | enqury_test12 | 7       |
+------------+---------------+---------+
```

From the above tables its clear that, each branch contains a number of users.
These users post multiple enquiries.
I need to get the total number of enquiries in each branch as

`branch id => number of enquiries`

I have tried various queries. But i couldn't get the result. Any one can help?
I am using `MySQL` and i need a **single query** to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please just relax some of the member have posted the answer. You can check his answer first. :) @Blank Head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `count` and `group by`

```
select
b.branch_id,
count(e.user_id) as `total_enq`
from Branch b
left join User u on u.branch = b.branch_id
left join Enquiry e on e.user_id = u.user_id
group by b.branch_id
```

Comment: Thanks @abhik. I ll check it and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have to perform to get you desired result is like this :-

```
$query = "SELECT u.branch, COUNT(u.user_id) AS `total_enquires` 
          FROM enquiry e INNER JOIN user u ON e.user_id = u.user_id
          GROUP BY u.branch"
```

This will help you,and i think you don't need to join **branch** table as **user** table already contain `branch_id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        bt.branch_id
        ,COUNT(enquiry_id) AS total_enquiry
FROM 
    enquiry_table et
    INNER JOIN user_table ut on ut.user_id = et.user_id
    INNER JOIN branch_table bt ON bt.branch_id = ut.branch
WHERE  
    1=1
GROUP BY
        bt.branch_id
```

you can try this

Answer (score 0):

This is the query

```
SELECT `branch`,`branch_name`,count(`user`.`user_id`),count(`enquiry_id`) FROM `user` inner join `branch` on `user`.`branch`=`branch`.`branch_id` inner join `enquiry` on `user`.`user_id`=`enquiry`.`user_id` group by `branch`
```

try it here 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf3eb/1